# Issue with mapping goDaddy's domain to aws elastic beanstalk URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to map godaddy's domain to AWS elastic beanstalk URL. I gone through AWS [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html)  and followed the same, but still I can't get it to work.

Whenever I enter

> mydomainname.com

, I am seeing only blank screen but the actual amazon elastic beanstalk url works fine.

I found few other posts on this discussion forum & stackoverflow related to this problem, but no luck.

Even I tried with Router 53 method, it's not working at all.

Now I'm stuck on this task.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: can you share the real domain name?

Comment: I am pointing my GoDaddy domains nameservers to Route 53 and use A-record aliases to my cloud front distrubutions and load balancers from there. It works great.

If you are using load balancers and scaling you want to point it to the load balancer.

Comment: You've given zero information that can be used to debug/answer this.

Comment: does www.mydomainname.com works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the same these days... In godaddy you have to follow 2 steps... If you followed [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html) I guess you already got sep 1.

1. In ZONE FILE, create a CName (Alias)
   www pointing to yourapp.elasticbeanstalk.com
2. In Settings -> forwarding: forward to www.mydomain.com
   301 (Permanent), Forward only.

Keep in mind that this changes might take a while to propagate.